# Form without value atribute in the submit input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this form:

```
<form action="http://xxx" method="post">
    <img src="" id="imagenOriginal">

    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" /> 

    <label>Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" /> 

    <input id="a" type="submit"  value"  "name="btnRegistro">
</form>
```

And if I dont set a value to the submit input the form dont submit , but if I put value="SEND" or any thing its make the submit ? Why occurs that?

Comment: It's obviously a syntax error. If you do not want to set a value just use this: <input id="a" type="submit" name="btnRegistro">

Comment: The value can be empty. The problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
<input id="a" type="submit"  value="" name="btnRegistro">
```

Comment: Yes but if I put like that dont send me the form.